# Strange appearance of drop-down menu in ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, unity

Sorry for the unclear description using 'Strange appearance', but I really can't come up with a suitable word to describe this. Please look at the screenshot.

I've noticed this strange appearance at least from ubuntu 12.04, I'm shocked that this bug still exists in ubuntu 16.04.

When I move the window to the edge of screen, click the drop-down menu, this bug appears. I've googled a lot using keywords such as 'ubuntu drop-down menu bug', 'ubuntu drop-down menu strange appearance' but still got nothing help.

The version of my Ubuntu is 16.04, the version of unity is 7.4.0.

[image: Strange appearance of drop-down menu in ubuntu]

Comment: Does this problem occur when you're logged into the Guest account?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, it happens even in installation via a live cd.

Comment: Which drop down menu are you clicking on? Have you checked that you have the correct/current video driver installed? Have you checked for a BIOS update?

Comment: @heynnema It seems that all drop down menus in unity have this bug. I use intel GPU (HD 3000) and I have the latest BIOS version (HP laptop g4-2318tx).

Comment: Do you have `intel-microcode` installed? In `terminal`, type `dpkg -l intel-microcode | grep ii` to find out.

Comment: @heynnema Yes, I have the microcode installed. This is the output of your command : ii  intel-microcode 3.20151106.1 amd64        Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs

Comment: Good. Something must be strange with your system or video card, because I've never heard of your problem, esp when booted to the Live DVD. You might try booting the Live DVD with `nomodeset` kernel parameter and see if the problem still occurs. That might prove/disprove that it's a video card/driver related problem.